# Locate and update runtime created object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Haven't found a duplicate answer to this yet, so here goes..

I need to create 'objects' (could be key:value pair, but I need to databind) during runtime from data I receive from a serial port.

For example I'll receive "012320.50".  I am breaking this into an object/key for "0123" with a value of "20.50".  I also need to databind a control to this. I can't know how many, or the 'name' of these sources until the data is streamed in.  So i need to create them dynamically.

That said, I was planning on using a list of objects...but I hope there is a better solution.  And I haven't figured out how to bind to these yet...?

Mock-example:

```
class myObject{
    int Name{get;set;}
    double Value{get;set}
}

Dictionary<int, myObject> dict = new Dictionary<int, myObject>();
```

when serial data is received I parse then create the object:

```
dict.Add(name, new myObject(Name=name, Value = value});
```

Now for my questions:

1. When the value comes through again for a source, how can I reference that and assign a new value? I was thinking of iterating through the Dictionary and if(Name == name) kinda stuff to change the value, but I'm thinking that's terrible and inefficient.  Hopefully someone has a better way?
2. How can I databind a control to the same object?  Not sure here at all...just starting with WPF.  I understand how to databind...but to a dynamic object, not so much.

Comment: why not create a custom class ? there are several options / approaches to how you could do this .. I believe that if you do not want duplicate key / value pairs then I would create a Class and then create a `List<SomeClass>` of some class

Comment: `So basically you could create a public or protected List<myObject> someObjList = new List<myObject>();`

Comment: I agree, and that was my thought with the Dictionary...a list would be ok too, but then the only way to manipulate the value of the object would be to iterate the list...each time the value changes.  I probably will be getting 10+ of these per second.

Comment: Is there a better way to identify the runtime created object to change it's value, other than just a list index?

Comment: 10/second is not a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the information...That's the way I'm going at the moment.